# Custom QGraphicsView is painting on other widgets

Tags: c++, qt, events, qgraphicsview, qpainter

In Qt/c++, I have an overloaded/custom QGraphicsView class.
In this classes' drawBackground event function (same issue happens with paintEvent), I am drawing some lines using the provided Qpainter:

```
void myGraphicsView::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{
    QGraphicsView::drawBackground(painter, rect);
    QPen pen;    
    pen.setWidth(2);
    painter->setPen(pen);

    painter->drawLine(rect.x(),rect.y(),rect.x()+rect.width(),rect.y()+rect.height());
}
```

Initialization of the GraphicsView custom class:

```
myGraphicsView::myGraphicsView(GLWidget *myOpenGLWindow,QWidget * parent) : QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
    myScene=new actionEditorButtons(this);
    myScene->setMainView(this);
    setScene(myScene);
    setStyleSheet("background: transparent");
    setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom);
}
```

Initialization of the custom QGraphicsScene, with a button that gets "corrupted" with the line drawn in the custom graphicsview:

```
actionEditorButtons::actionEditorButtons(BrainClass *theBrain,int receivedActionNb,QObject *parent) : QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
    beginButton = new QPushButton();
    beginButton->setIcon(QIcon(":/icons/actionBegin.png"));
    beginButton->setIconSize(QSize(40,40));
    beginButton->setFixedSize(QSize(40,40));
    beginButton->setStyleSheet("border: none");
    beginProxy=addWidget(beginButton);
    beginProxy->setPos(0,80);
    connect(beginButton, SIGNAL (released()),this, SLOT (handleBeginButton()));
}
```

My issue is that this line is not only drawn on this custom QGraphicsView, but it is drawn too on all widgets added this scene. How can I only draw in the main graphicsView and not in the added widgets ?

Comment: Add the code with your using of these qgraphicsscene objects and qgraphicsviews.

Comment: Edited text, adding code

Comment: I am facing a pretty similar issue, where the QGraphicsView is drawing the scene not only on itself, but also over any widget that is around it, as if it wasn't clipping the scene to the view rectangle. Have you found a solution? If so, could you post it?

Comment: I finished by escaping from the drawBackground function, and instead using  a QGraphicsLineItem.